# sharing a users folder as admin

Tags: box-api

Trying to figure out if I can do the following via the box-api.

1. authenticate as an enterprise admin
2. lookup a user (in our case a special box user named "group_xxx" where this account will serve as a non-person shared group like "group_math_dept", "group_engineering_dept", etc...).
3. query for the root folder info for a given user-id (perhaps "GET /users//folders/0"
   (tried that it doesn't work).
4. View the list of enterprise users with whom the given folder has been shared.
5. Modify the list of enterprise users with whom the given folder has been shared.

What I'd like to do is develop an app to delegate admin of these special group accounts to an appropriate individual in the given group. We can maintain who admins what locally. I can authenticate as one of our Box Admins (i.e. I have working code for steps 1 and 2). However, I don't see support in the API v2.0 doc for steps 3, 4, and 5.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my understanding is the same as what you've found; that account and meta operations like steps 3 through 5 are not currently supported through the API.

UPDATE:
Looking at Box's developers blog it looks like functionality for steps 4 and 5 were actually just added, but are not yet in the documentation.

http://developers.blog.box.com/2012/09/10/v2-api-updates-keep-rolling/

Answer (score 0):

Box actually has some more enterprise/admin API methods in private beta.  Those are made accessible to early testers for a controlled environment, and include methods to perform operations on behalf of other users with administrative privileges.

If you're interested, feel free to email api [at] box [dot] com to discuss the testing of beta methods.